# How to fix warning page_cache_extension is deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I using rails 4.0. when I start server, I got the warning as below

> DEPRECATION WARNING: page_cache_extension is deprecated and will be
>   removed from Rails 4.1 (use default_static_extension instead). (called
>   from get at
>   /home/khanh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:201)

how to remove this warning?

Comment: The message is pretty self-explanatory: Rails 4.0 has deprecated ActionController::Base.page_cache_extension option. Use ActionController::Base.default_static_extension instead. Do you use page caching?

Comment: no. I don't use page caching.

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile? Also if you have a git repo can you do a `$ git grep page_cache_extension`?

Comment: this is private repo. here is my gemfile: https://gist.github.com/khanhnguyen/8517388